# Wireless adapter deleted itself out of the blue?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I was on my computer (Acer V Nitro Black Edition running Windows 10) watching something on Netflix and had to leave so I paused my video. Upon my return, my computer was still on the screen with my video but for whatever reason I was no longer connected to the Internet.

So I started to troubleshoot as one would normally do in my predicament. I found that the wireless adapter does not show itself in my network options, nor does it even show up in device manager.

The function key to toggle Wi-Fi on or off on the laptop keyboard does nothing as well. I have rebooted and still have the same problem. How does something like this even happen? I am stumped and would really like to fix it.

Looking online I saw that other people have had similar things happen with Windows 10 while connecting through a VPN but that is not the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found out that the answer to my troubles was just Windows updates. My computer was stuck in a state where it had downloaded the new updates and I guess something glitchy happened after.

Rebooting would not trigger the "applying windows update" screen. I ended up doing a hard shutdown and when I restarted, that screen came up, did it's thing and my wireless adapter was back without issue.

I don't even think I could re-create the issue if I tried, however that's not to say it couldn't happen to someone else.